# Is there a way to simulate VR input devices on WebVR - A-Frame?

Tags: aframe, webvr, oculus, htc-vive, webxr

I'm currently using A-Frame to build WebXR (WebVR) applications, and
it's not always that I'm able to have the controllers (Oculus Touch, Vive Controls) with me to test them out. Is there a way to "simulate" the events that the different controllers emit?

Comment: It currently emulates an older version of the WebVR API, but this may work for you: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webvr-api-emulation/gbdnpaebafagioggnhkacnaaahpiefil?hl=en

Comment: Thanks :) Do I have a way to emulate the controllers with the API emulation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about lower levels, but i have an idea on a higher one:
If you have your vive controllers, and want to test out oculus touch events, you could do some mapping.

I'd do a component, intercepting the original events, and emitting new ones with the same details:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("event-mapper", {
  init: function() {
    let viveEvents = ["menuup", "menudown"]
    let oculusEvents = ["gripdown", "gripup"]
    viveEvents .forEach((event, index) => {
      this.el.addEventListener(event, (e) => {
        this.el.emit(oculusEvents [index], {detail: e})
      })
    })
  }
}
```

If you want it to be "dynamic" you could use a real Map() instead of two arrays, but here it seems redundant.

Furthermore, by including the `detail` in the emitted event, all details, values, targets also get passed with the new event.

---

So when you want your entity to react to the mapped events, you can just do:

```
<a-entity event-mapper></a-entity>
```

Check it out in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3zv1ghLb/5/) (mapped some mouse events, onto made up ones)

Comment: Interesting approach :) .By any chance, do the emitted events give you the exact output from the original devices. I mean, will they output the keys and values from the original gripdown event? (Or are they the same?)

Comment: shoot, I forgot about the most important part :D I've updated my fiddle + anwser (the way the event is emitted)